# Java - Centering Text (on a Canvas)

Tags: java, awt, fontmetrics

thanks for checking out my question.

I am working a menu for the game that I'm making, and I want to center the game's title on the main menu. I've looked at several questions here on Stack Overflow, but couldn't find an answer.

**Problem**

The problem that I'm having is that whenever I call my `centerString()` method, it puts it in the center of the y-axis, but not of the x-axis. What am I doing wrong here?

**Code**

*Method code*

```
private void centerString(String txt, int width, int height, Graphics g, Font font) {
        FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
        int x = (width - metrics.stringWidth(txt)) / 2;
        int y = (metrics.getAscent() + (height - (metrics.getAscent() + metrics.getDescent())) / 2);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(txt, x, y);
}
```

*Where it's called*

```
final Font fnt = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 36);
centerString("ThatMarioEngine", toInt(screenSize.getWidth()), toInt(screenSize.getHeight()), g, fnt);
```

Comment: You should probably set the font before getting the font metrics. No clue if that's your (only) problem though.

Comment: Have you print out the value of "width" to see if you're getting the correct screen width?

Comment: I've found the problem, now I just need the solution. I'm grabbing the size of the computer screen, though I meant to get the size of the window...
Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: There's a getWidth(), getHeight() and even getSize() method for all GUI components in Java.

Comment: Ok. I now get the right window size, and the text *starts*  at the `width / 2`, but it didn't subtract the `width / 2` of the text. I've fixed that by following @Dukeling 's tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by making using the windows size, instead of the screen size. The centering issue was fixed by putting `g.setFont(font);` *before* I get the FontMetrics.